# What is the differenece between Shape s = new Circle(); and Shape * s = new Circle();

Tags: c++, oop

It was an interview question that we write `Shape s = new Circle();` where `Shape` is an `abstract class`.

What is difference between `s` and a pointer of shape type like `Shape * s = new Circle();`?

Comment: Was there a specific language referred to in the question?

Comment: Presumably this is a [tag:c++] question - but please edit your question and add whatever language tag is appropriate.

Comment: Yes it was C++ question.

Comment: `Shape s = new Circle()` should be an error

Comment: Maybe as part of the interview question they talked about how they were using a preprocessor macro to redefine Shape as a pointer to a circle object? Then again, maybe not.

Comment: At the very least, the point of the question was to spot rudimentary erros...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two statements are quite distinct from one another, I'm going with the easy (and correct) one first:

## The pointer

```
Shape * s = new Circle();
```

As you already mentioned, `s` is a *pointer-to-`Shape`* in this case. The statement declares `s`, and assigns a pointer of type `Circle` to it. This implies that `Circle` is derived from `Shape`.

Because C++ is a polymorphic language, `s` does now point to an object of type `Circle`. If `Shape` has [virtual functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual) that are overloaded by `Circle`, calls to those functions on `s` will be redirected to the overloading `Circle` implementation.

A simple *and incomplete* example (note that in C++, there are [no by-keyword defined](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/abstract_class) `abstract classes`):

```
class Shape{
    virtual int getX() = 0; //getX() is purely virtual, so Shape is abstract   
}
class Circle : public Shape{
    int getX() override;
}

Shape * s = new Circle();

int myX = s->getX(); //will call Circle::getX()
```

This is basic polymorphic behaviour, and one of the foundation stones of Object Oriented Programming in C++. Also note that the [override keyword](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) is not entirely necessary, I just personally consider it to be good style.

## The Object

```
Shape s = new Circle();
```

This statement looks nearly like the first one, but does something completely different. First of all, `s` is now the actual object, which is good and bad at the same time. It's good because it will get automatically destroyed as soon as the current [compound statement](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/statements#Compound_statement) is left, freeing all memory occupied by it.

But it's bad because `s` can not be polymorphic anymore: It is declared as a `Shape`-Object, and nothing else. With the code from above, and your premise that `Shape` is an abstract class, that wouldn't even work. Abstract classes cannot be instantiated, because they have unimplemented functions.

If we assumed that it wasn't abstract, we would fall into a lot of implicit conversion loopholes, which I only want to describe in a short fashion:

In order for the above statement to be correct C++ code, `Shape` would need to have a constructor that takes one argument of type `Circle*`, that is *not* declared as `explicit`. This would make `Shape s = new Circle();` equivalent to `Shape s = Shape(new Circle());`. An [implicit conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast) takes place.

This is *very*, ***very*** bad code! `new Circle()` allocates memory for a `Circle` object that can never be freed, because it has no name! This is called a memory leak, and it's the reason why you should almost *never* use naked pointers in C++ any more. The alternative is called [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory), and you should use them whenever possible.

Additionally, to prevent things like this from happening, you should declare all your constructors `explicit` (or at least the ones that take only one argument):

```
explicit Shape(Circle *);
```

---

Finally, I would like to encourage you to [read at least one, better a few books about C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Everything I just explained is super basic stuff that you should really know, and this is not the best place to learn it. C++ is a dangerous language, you can do a lot of things very wrong, even if they seem to work initially.

Comment: Good answer, I'd also suggest to the original poster that if these concepts are confusing then its probably not the right time to be interviewing for C++ jobs!

Answer (score 1):

`new Circle` creates a dynamic object of type `Circle` and gives a pointer to it. That pointer can be used to initialise a pointer to `Circle` or any base class of `Circle`; so assuming that `Circle` derives from `Shape`, the second form

```
Shape * s = new Circle;
```

gives a pointer of (static) type `Shape*`, pointing to an object of (dynamic) type `Circle`. This can be used polymorphically, to interact with the `Circle` via the abstract interface defined by `Shape`, without needing to know that the actual type is `Circle`.

The first, incorrect, example

```
Shape s = new Circle;
```

attempts to create an object of type `Shape`, initialised with the pointer to `Circle`. Being abstract, `Shape` can't be instantiated except as part of a derived class, so this fails to compile.

When you use `new`, always remember to `delete` the dynamic objects when you've finished with them or, better still, use [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) classes such as smart pointers to handle that error-prone tedium for you. Also, make sure that `Shape` has a virtual destructor so that its derived types can be safely deleted.